# Reducer/state organization for large objects

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a react native app that uses many screens to manage the data in a large object.

For example, each of the following is a screen to manage a portion of 1 object in this app: address, contacts, images, notes, and a few more.

Is there any issue that would conflict with best practices or performance to use a single reducer which passes back the entire object in state?

or should my reduces and state be more screen oriented, passing back only the properties of the object that each screen is handling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight forward answer. **It depends**

Depends on the data stored by each `reducer`.(state maintained by each)

If it's complex data better to create a separate `reducer`.

If each screen's state is just a flat `JSON` object, keep all of them in single `reducer`.

At the end `combineReducers()` will make them all available for us at any place we want by simple `connect()` method of `redux`.

Generally we'll maintain a `reducer` for `container` where container holds the components which are hydrated by `reducer` of this container.

It's not an issue even if we maintain a 'reducer' for each `component`.

And one more good practice is to keep **related** state say:

`cart` => cartReducer which in turn accepts all actions on the state of `cart` like `ADD_TO_CART`, `RESET_CART`, `CHECKOUT_CART`, `DELETE_ITEM` etc.

And in your case if address, contacts, images etc are related to a single entity, better to maintain a single `reducer`.